# JS regex to match a username with specific special characters and no consecutive spaces

Tags: javascript, html, regex, pattern-matching, spaces

I am pretty new to this reg ex world. Struck up with small task regarding Regex.
Before posting new question I have gone thru some answers which am able to understand but couldnt crack the solution for my problem
Appreciate your help on this.

My Scenario is:

Validating the Username base on below criteria

1- First character has to be a-zA-Z0-9_@ (either of two special characters(_@) or alphanumeric)

2 - The rest can be any letters, any numbers and -@_  (either of three special characters and alphanumeric).

3 - BUT no consecutive spaces between words.

4- Max size should be 30 characters

my username might contain multiple words seperated by single space..for the first word only _@ alphanumeric are allowed and for the second word onwards it can contain _-@aphanumeric

Need to ignore the Trailing spaces at the end of the username

Examples are: @test, _test, @*test123, 123@*, test_-@, test -test1, @test -_@test etc...

Appreciate your help on this..

Thanks
Arjun

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
^(?!.*[ ]{2,})[\w@][-@\w]{0,29}$
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3PK6ki/1/).
Condition 3 is ambigouus though as you're not allowing spaces anyway. `\w` is a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z_]`, `(?!...)` is called a neg. lookahead.

---

Broken down this says:

```
^             # start of string
(?!.*[ ]{2,}) # neg. lookahead, no consecutive spaces
[\w@]         # condition 1
[-@\w]{0,29}  # condition 2 and 4
$             # end of string
```

Comment: Hey Jan, Thanks for your prompt response.. May b i didnt framed my question correctly...your solution working flawlessly for the single word..But my username might contain multiple words seperated by single space..for the first word only _@ alphanumeric are allowed and for the second word onwards it can contain _-@aphanumeric.. Examples- _test -test,    test -_test, test _test123 etc

Answer (score 0):

This might work `^(?=.{1,30}$)(?!.*[ ]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_@]+(?:[ ][a-zA-Z0-9_@-]+)*$`

Note - the check for no consecutive spaces `(?! .* [ ]{2} )` is not really
necessary since the regex body only allows a single space between words.
It is left in for posterity, take it out if you want.

Explained

```
 ^                        # BOS
 (?= .{1,30} $ )          # Min 1 character, max 30
 (?! .* [ ]{2} )          # No consecutive spaces (not really necessary here)
 [a-zA-Z0-9_@]+           # First word only
 (?:                      # Optional other words
      [ ] 
      [a-zA-Z0-9_@-]+ 
 )*
 $                        # EOS
```